# Sending and receiving text using C network sockets and Linux terminal

Tags: c, networking, ncurses, tui

I am trying to build a C application which will allow 2 users to connect and exchange text messages. The application will provide users with a simple TUI built using the ncurses library, and for networking, I am using libevent.

What I don't understand is can I just read characters on one side and print them on the other using library functions? Could this allow a malicious user to send special characters like the ones ncurses uses to manipulate the terminal, and that way send instructions to the receiving user's terminal? Also, do I need to worry about character encoding when reading the characters using ncurses library functions from stdin and sending them over the network?

I searched the web and failed to find the appropriate solution. If you could provide me with an explanation or point me to some other literature where I could find the answer, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I don't think the ncurses functions for displaying text send the raw text to the terminal. If it contains escape sequences they won't be sent.

Comment: But you could test it youself to be sure.

Comment: Validating and sanitizing data received from an untrusted source is usually a good idea, yes.

Comment: @Shawn The developers of New World learned that lesson.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I tested ncurses printing functions like `printw()`, when I tried to send color escape codes like `\e[0;31m`, they were printed like `^[[0;31m`. So it seems that ncurses library takes care of removing escape characters when printing.